# Storing tweets in MongoDB using pymongo

Tags: python, mongodb

I am trying to save tweets directly from `Twitter` into `MongoDB` for retrieval later, but I keep getting error messages with regards to `json`. Someone please help! Here is the sample codes with error messages.

```
searcher = keywordSearcher('','','') ## this is an object class
client = MongoClient('localhost', 27017)
db = client.test_dbase  ## connect to database twitter
collection = db.rio_olympics ## create a collection object
result = searcher.getTwitterComment('Olympics 2016', '21 August 2016', 2) ## this is where I query Twitter Search API

py_dict = json.load(result)
post_id = collection.insert_many(py_dict)
```

error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/edidiong/myWorkSpace/keywordSearchTest.py", line 12, in <module>
    class keywordSearchTest:
  File "/home/edidiong/myWorkSpace/keywordSearchTest.py", line 45, in keywordSearchTest
    py_dict = json.load(result)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/__init__.py", line 287, in load
    return loads(fp.read(),
  AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'read'
```

Comment: BTW. `collection.insert_many(py_dict)` looks strange. `insert_many` inserts multiple documents, thus it expects a `list`. Use `insert_one` to insert just one document.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message indicates you are trying to `load` a dictionary object. This means you already have a dictionary object. I'm not sure what the point of the `json.load` would be even if it did work.

So you can probably just do:

```
py_dict = searcher.getTwitterComment("Olympics 2016", '21 August 2016', 2)
post_id = collection.insert_many(py_dict)
```

Comment: Thanks very much L-Jones9 for your help...I also had to change the last line to collection.insert(py_dict)

Answer (score 1):

Your `searcher.getTwitterComment`  returns a dictionary and not json.

That is why you get this error, `json.load()` is already called probably.